# Post request in laravel using guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, curl, slack-api, guzzle

I am trying to notify a slack channel whenever a new order appears in our site. But I am struggling to perform this CURL request in Laravel

`curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"channel\": \"#new-order\", \"username\": \"product-notifier\", \"text\": \"New Orders: \n https://mission-control.airbringr.com/orders/item/411980\", \"icon_emoji\": \":smiley:\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/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`

I've been trying to come up with a solution:

```
    public function slack(Request $request){
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        try {
        
            $client = new Client();
            
            $response = $client->post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/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',[
                'json' => [
                    'payload' =>
                        ['channel'=>'#new-order','username'=> 'product-notifier', 'text'=>'New Orders: \n https://mission-control.airbringr.com/orders/item/411980', 'icon_emoji'=>':smiley:']
                        ],
                        ]
                        
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 400);
        }
        return response()->json(["message" => "notified successfully"], 200);
    }
```

But I am getting `` "Client error: `POST https:\/\/hooks.slack.com\/services\/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` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\nmissing_text_or_fallback_or_attachments\n" ``

**but the curl request works just fine in my terminal.**

Any suggestions on how can I make this work?

Comment: Your cURL command is _not_ making a JSON request ... `--data-urlencode` means this is a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request. The _value_ of the one parameter `payload` is a string containing JSON, but that does not make the request itself a JSON request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atleast you do not need to wrap you data in a payload key. Which you can see in the documentation [here](https://api.slack.com/messaging/sending).

```
$response = $client->post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/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',[
    'json' => [
        'channel'=>'#new-order',
        'username'=> 'product-notifier',
        'text'=>'New Orders: \n https://mission-control.airbringr.com/orders/item/411980', 'icon_emoji'=>':smiley:'
        ]
    ],
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. should have read the document more carefully